# Sending Images with nextcord (Application didn't respond)

Tags: python, nextcord

Im trying to send a image but when I send only the image it sends the image and then says that the application didn't respond I tried sending a ephemeral message but to me it looks kind of messy

```
@slash_command(name='somename', description='description', guild_ids=[id])
async def text(self, ctx : Interaction):
    channel = ctx.channel
    await ctx.response.send_message("somemessage", ephemeral=True)
    await channel.send(file=nextcord.File('somepicture.png'))
```

Comment: What question are you asking? Also, are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: When I try to send only the image it says that the application didn’t respond in discord I get no errors in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the interaction need to be [acknowledged](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=nextcord%20interactionresponse#nextcord.InteractionResponse) by your bot.

you can do this by using [.defer](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=defer#nextcord.InteractionResponse.defer)
optional you can deleting the last message

```
@slash_command()
async def image(self, interaction : Interaction):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    message = await interaction.channel.fetch_message(int(interaction.channel.last_message_id))
    await interaction.channel.send("somemessage", files=[nextcord.File('somepicture.png')])
    await message.delete()
```